# startActivityForResult() deprecation. I am currently learning google android app fundamental course by google;

Tags: android

I am finding what to write in place of startActivityForResult() method . This code in present in google android app fundamentals course here [https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#5[enter](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#5%5Benter) link description here][1](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#5) . I want

```
enter code herepackage com.example.twoactivity;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import [...];

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = 
AppCompatActivity.class.getSimpleName();
// this is a public string so second activity can use it
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = 
"com.example.android.twoactivity.extra.MESSAGE"; 
private EditText mMessageEditText;
public static final int TEXT_REQUEST = 1;
private TextView mReplyHeadTextView;
private TextView mReplyTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // getting the reference to the entered string
    mMessageEditText = findViewById(R.id.editText_main); 
    mReplyHeadTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_header_reply);
    mReplyTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_message_reply);

}

public void launchSecondaryActivity(View view) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "BUTTON CLICKED");     
// reference to call secondary activtiy     
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondaActivity.class);     

    String message = mMessageEditText.getText().toString(); // 
getting the entered string in message
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

    // WHAT to write write here exactly 
    ** startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT_REQUEST); **
  

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to register for result

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                     
                    }
                }
            });

public void launchSecondaryActivity(View view) {
    //do your stuff and then
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    activityForResult.launch(intent);
}
```

Comment: Where to add that code in onCreate() or in launchSecondaryActivity() ? see the code

Comment: activityForResult outside of onCreate and call launch function from button or some view

Comment: @SatendraPal then accept this as solution

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Activity Result API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

```java
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Handle the returned Uri
        }
});

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    // ...

    Button selectButton = findViewById(R.id.select_button);

    selectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Pass in the mime type you'd like to allow the user to select
            // as the input
            mGetContent.launch("image/*");
        }
    });
}
```